# ASP.NET C# Entity Framework - How to update Foreign Key properly? - Part 2

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

This question is like a Part 2 of my [previous one here!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12373899/asp-net-c-sharp-entity-framework-how-to-update-foreign-key-properly)

Here are things I learned and hoping to be true:

1. Do not use Data Entity Context as Static
2. Dispose the data context after used -usually after one time-
3. Pass parameters into UPDATING Entity method instead of the Entity
   (which I'll explain and in here my crossroad lies)

Here is my modified code:

```
public class ManagerBase
    {
        private NoxonEntities _entities = null;

        public NoxonEntities Entities
        {
            get
            {
                if (_entities == null)
                    _entities = new NoxonEntities();

                return _entities;
            }
        }
    }

//Managers uses ManagerBase class as a Base class
MemberManager currentMemberManager = new MemberManager();
currentMemberManager.Save(memberId, username, password, languageId);


//MemberManager class
public Member Save(long memId, string username, string password, int langId)
        {
            using (var Context =   base.Entities)
            {
                var Data = Context.Member.First(c => c.Id == memId);

                Data.Username = username;
                Data.Password = password;
                Data.Language = Context.Language.First(c => c.Id == langId); //Gets the foreign entity

                Context.SaveChanges();

                return Data;
            }
        }
```

This works without exception. But normally this **SAVE** method is an implemented method by an **interface**. So, I'd rather to pass an **OBJECT** value to the SAVE method than **passing all the fields** like above.
For example I'd like to use this:

```
//Member is an EntityFramework Object which was created during EF Model when I added by visual studio
//Filter is the method that returns an EntityFramework Object from EF (and eventually database) with given some arguments
//SomeArguments could be  MemberId = 2
Member modifiedMember = currentMemberManager.Filter(someArguments);
modifiedMember.UserName = "newvalue";
currentMemberManager.Save(modifiedMember);
```

In the SAVE method perhaps I could use like this:

```
public Member Save(Member modifiedMember)
            {
                using (var Context =   base.Entities)
                {
                    var Data = Context.Member.First(c => c.Id == modifiedMember.Id);

                    Data.Username = modifiedMember.Username;
                    Data.Password = modifiedMember.Password;
                    Data.Language = Context.Language.First(c => c.Id == modifiedMember.LanguageId); //Gets the foreign entity

                    Context.SaveChanges();

                    return Data;
                }
            }
```

If I am gonna use this just like the one right above, I think I should NOT use the passing object EF Object and instead perhaps I should use some other class that I'll write just to map the parameters to the EF Member Entity.

**First question: Is this a good approach?**

```
public class MyMember
{
    public long Id { set; get; }
    public string Username { set; get; }
    public string Password { set; get; }
    public int LanguageId { set; get; }
}

MyMember.Username = "NewValue";
MyMember.LanguageId = 4; //4 as in new value
currentMemberManager.Save(MyMember); //As you can see MyMember is not an EF Entity in here
```

But this will take long time since there is already some written code.

**Second question: Can't I use an EF Entity object *OUTSIDE* and modify it there to save it *IN* the *MemberManager* class?**

Again, thank you very much for your help in advance.

Comment: I had an answer on this link.

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389704/how-to-update-entity][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389704/how-to-update-entity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer:

[How to update entity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12389704/how-to-update-entity)

And I thank you for the ones who helped me.