# How to update entity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework-4

I had a question more detailed earlier which I had no answer, I will have the same question with a simpler way:

I have an EF database with foreign key to another table.
[image]

I would like to **UPDATE** an ***ENTITY***. But I need to this like this and I'll write the codes below:

1. Go to database and **retrieve** the Member by id, return EF Member object
2. Do some changes on the object **OUTSIDE** the EF Context
3. Send the **MODIFED** EF Member into a Save method
4. In BL layer save method uses the context and save changes.

1)

```
MemberManager currentMemberManager = new MemberManager();
Member NewMember = currentMemberManager.GetById(2);
```

2)

```
NewMember.FirstName = "NewFirstName";
NewMember.LanguageId = 1;
```

3)

```
currentMemberManager.Save(NewMember);
```

4)

```
public void Save2(Member newMember)
{
    using (var Context = new NoxonEntities())
    {
        Member existingMember = Context.Member.First(c => c.Id == newMember.Id);
        existingMember.FirstName = newMember.FirstName;
        existingMember.Language = Context.Language.First(c => c.Id == newMember.LanguageId);
        Context.SaveChanges();//In here I get the error below
    }
}
```

> The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error
>   occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be
>   in an inconsistent state. Inner exception message: A referential
>   integrity constraint violation occurred: The property values that
>   define the referential constraints are not consistent between
>   principal and dependent objects in the relationship.
>
> **Note**: You may suggest to SEND a different class (Ex: public class
>   MyMember) that has all the necessary properties and totally separated
>   from EF. But this requires much work to get all EF object converting
>   into my separate classes. Am I right?

I am hoping there is a way to Detach the entity just long enough for me to modify it and save the values into database. (Also, I tried the Detach method which updates no rows at all)

I've been trying to solve this for hours now.

Please, help me to understand it better, I really need a solution. Thank you so much to anyone how has some ideas.

Comment: Does a Language with the ID you're setting on the new member exist in the database?  If not you'll need to Add it to the context before saving changes.

Comment: Yes. The Id related to the Language Id exists on the Language Table already.. So there are no relation problems.

Comment: Instead of Context.Member.First, maybe you can try using the Attach method

Comment: Thank you Igoncalves.. Mark Oreta suggest something very similar and worked perfectly for me.. I was looking for a way to steal away the object from the EF and send it back to EF again and Mark solved my problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you do something simple like detaching the entity, then attaching it to the context when you're ready to save?

```
MemberManager currentMemberManager = new MemberManager();
Member NewMember = currentMemberManager.GetById(2);
```

The get:

```
public Member GetById(int id)
{ 
  var member = YourContext.Members.FirstOrDefault(m => m.id == id);
  YourContext.Detach(member);
  return member;
}
```

The save:

```
public void Save2(Member newMember)
        {
            using (var Context = new NoxonEntities())
            {
                Context.Attach(newMember);
                Context.ObjectStateManager.ChangeObjectState(newMember, EntityState.Modified);
                Context.SaveChanges();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Oh my god! Thats it! In fact exactly it!... Thank you so much Mark!.. I have been struggling with this problem! 
So, was the basic idea is to DETACH from the EF when you retrieve the object for general purposes over the session?

Comment: Correct - Get the entity, detach it so you can do what you want to do, and then when it's time you can reattach it to save the changes.  This prevents your context from existing too long.

Comment: A word of caution when using detached and re-attached entites, you can and will find yourself in strife with concurrent editing this way. (2 users editing the same data) user 1 gets an object and starts editing a detached instance. User 2 does the same. Depending on the ORM behavior you either get a race condition (last in wins) or a version mismatch error. (NHibernate, not sure about EF) Typically it's better to reload the entity and check versions, then transcribe the values from either the detached entity (or view model) back into the "live" entity.